# Add python.exe to the path on Windows

Tags: python3

My Windows 10 has Python 2.7 installed. I don't have admin privileges' and can't un-install it.
I installed Python 3 now. Hence I have 2 versions ... but I want that default be Python 3.
I created User environment variable with the path to Python 3 .. but when I execute python.exe from command line it still point to 2.7
Hence my question: how could I trick it and make Python 3 be my default executable?
Thanks

Comment: change the `PATH` environment variable, or run `python3`, or if you use powershell then just set python as an alias to python3

Comment: @phuclv - the point is that I don't have admin permission. Hence when I go to System Environment app .. that section is disabled for me. BTW: could I change PATH env variables. from command line? Will it allow me without admin privileges ?

Comment: no, `PATH` is your local variable so no need to change the system PATH. Just update it in the [powershell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) `$env:PATH = "path\to\python3;$($env:PATH)"`, or set the variable manually in cmd `set "PATH=path\to\python3;%PATH%`

Comment: @phuclv - I do not have permission to modify PowerShell profile. Hence I've changed PATH and it's obviously worked ... but only for current session. Since I can't export this changes to make it permanent ... Eventually I fixed it myself by creating .bat file with the path to python3 and put that file in the folder where Python is installed. Thanks for your heads -up

Comment: the profile is **always** in your user folder so you're the only one with full access. It's personalized and not supposed for anyone else to use. If it doesn't exist you can simply create it

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have Python 2 and Python 3 and I wanted to start Python 3 from command line not by providing the absolute path but only executable itself. I was able to do it for current session only because I didn’t have permission to change PATH variable.
Solution was to create.bat file which has location of Python 3 and call it Python3.bat. I put it in the same directory where Python 3 is installed.
Now when I run Python.exe it starts Python 2. When I run Python3.exe it starts Python 3